# Correct way of using Keycloak in a Spring Boot REST application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, keycloak, openid-connect

### Reason why Keycloak was chosen

I stumbled across Keycloak when I looked at the project template of a colleague. They were provided with an Angular and Spring Boot app which uses a custom JWT mechanism to authenticate users ("stateless"). However, this is a *custom* solution (basically, the first solution you find online when you type in "Angular Spring Boot RBAC") and follows no specific protocol, it's just a ServletFilter that checks the request header for a Bearer token.

As you might imagine, while this works and is good enough for education-related fullstack programming which requires a basic form of RBAC, it raises a fair amount of issues, especially if the app should be extended with e.g. following features:

- What happens if we want to implement 2FA?
- As JWTs are stateless and are accepted until their lifespan is done, deleting the token from the session storage (Angular frontend/browser) does not permanently invalidate the token.
- Forgot password functionality
- Viewing the active sessions of a user
- What about security? Every feature has to be unit and integration tested to guarantee security
- and many more modern features that a proper account management system in a web app should have...

All of the above aspects are just way too tedious to handle manually and it would be re-inventing a perfectly fine OIDC/OAuth 2.0 wheel.

### Issue(s)

The application requires a role based access mechanism. This is fairly easy to do with Keycloak. Basically, instead of manually handling a "Users" entity in our Spring backend, we leave that part to the Keycloak server. Users at Keycloak have a unique ID per realm which can be extracted from the signed JWT in Spring in every request.

- However, what happens if the app requires storing relationships with the user, e.g. when a user creates an animal entry for an "animals" table (using the frontend), that animal entry should contain the ID and name of its creator. This information would then be stored in the Spring database and can be consumed by the frontend when listing all animals. However, if the creator decides to change their name at some later point, there would be inconsistencies in the "animals" table, as the previous username would not be valid any more.
- Another example would be a social network application. Suppose users want to send friendship requests to each other. In order to allow for a search by username, Keycloak's internal user management would have to be made public (that is, only the names of the users). How can one store which user is friends with which user? Would it be a n:m table that basically maps the Keycloak user IDs?
- How would you handle confidential information for users, e.g. their IBAN number to allow for online purchases or their residential address. Since we do not have a "Users" table on the Spring side, we must solely rely on Keycloak's user management. Adding claims to the token does not seem to be a sufficient solution, as the claims can be read by any attacker that gets hold of the JWT.

### Question

How would you prevent issues of above nature, that is, efficiently mapping the Keycloak user to a user of our own Spring application? I tried creating a "Users" table on the Spring side in conjunction to the "Users" table of Keycloak, but the synchronisation effort and prevention of redundancy seemed to be very difficult.

Answer (score 1):

As per latest Spring Security team (and many others) [latest recommandations](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/issues/297#issue-896744390), single page application should not be OAuth2 clients. The OAuth2 clients (what the authorization server issues tokens to) should only be on servers you trust enough to keep a secret actually secret.

You could have this client give access tokens to Angular so that it sends  requests to resource servers directly, but in my opinion (and in the opinion of much greater experts than me), it is much better to have requests authorized with sessions between Angular and a backend for frontend (BFF), and with access tokens only between the BFF and resource server.

If tokens do not leave your server (if it is not given to Angular app), then the question you have about tokens immutability is not a problem anymore: tokens are not remembered by stateless resource server (this is what "stateless" is about) and Spring clients with `oauth2Login` delete tokens in session when it end a session.

Spring Cloud Gateway is a perfect fit for a BFF: easy to configure with `oauth2Login` (get access tokens from Keycloak with `authorization_code` flow and then store it in session) and the `TokenRelay=` filter (replaces session cookie with the access token in session before forwarding a request from frontend to resource server). I wrote [a tutorial for that on Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-gateway-bff-oauth2).

Regarding your questions about multi-factor authentication, user registration, user account edition and deletion, all that is implemented by Keycloak already. You have nothing special to do to use it: just start the `authorization_code` flow and once the user redirected to Keycloak it handles things for you (including 2FA, forgot password, email verification and so on). You can also see active user sessions in Keycloak admin console. Maybe you'll want to provide Keycloak with one or more "themes" to better embrace your frontend look & feel, but that's all.

To link Keycloak users to your domain entities, you can use subject (`sub` claim in tokens) or any other immutable, unique and not-null value (`preferred_username` is frequently configured that way in Keycloak and provides with more user friendly values). Do not store in your database more than this Keycloak immutable keys: read user data from the token representation in Spring's `Authentication` instance in the security context or query Keycloak's REST API.

You don't really want to unit test Keycloak features: this is Keycloak's team job. What you should unit test are access control rules to your REST APIs. I wrote [an article at Baeldung about that](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-oauth-testing-access-control).

Comment: As per your last two paragraphs: 

The first one: I know that Keycloak has already implemented those features, that is why I put "
Reason why Keycloak was chosen" as a title.

The second one: The sub field is the unique ID of the Keycloak user. The problem arises when data that is subject to change is extracted from the token (e.g. change of the username) and then used in a n:m mapping in the application domain (that is, storing the name of the user who created an entry).

Comment: I edited my answer to cover more of your (many) questions. You shouldn't do that, by the way: a question should be more focused.